# What happens when application pool re-cycles in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I was using Session heavily for storing data of posted requests from client side on server. On research, various answers over stackoverflow pointing me , Not to use Session in ASP.NET MVC. Main reason is : Application Pool recycles frequently during life time of production server and this causes Session to recycle as well.

Thatswhy I am thinking to replace session objects with de-serialize able string "....".
My whole concern is : This singleton object containing this string (de-serialize able into Objects ) must not corrupt/recycle or re-initialize on app pool re-cycle.

So my final question would be  : What happens on app pool-recycle? Only Session re-cycles ? Or the whole memory re-cycles and re-initializes?

My target web server : Microsoft ASP.NET with MVC

Comment: Just adding on to this old answer that you really shouldn't use session ever.  Imo, it's bad code smell.  Relying heavily on session can create applications that don't adhere to web standards.  Like not being able to bookmark a url because new users won't have the session state properly setup for it to load.  It leads to LOTS of mistakes in development.  Instead you should use your own persistence, like a database, i.e. Entity Framework 6+, or PetaPoco, etc and back it with sql server or postgreSql etc.

Comment: So if you're not using session you might think, how to I get stuff on a request?  You look it up on every request, you make db calls to grab it.  It's 2021, instead of worrying about caching things on the backend, let the UI do it on the front end.  With SPA like designs with url state etc, the front end caches stuff and the back end doesn't have to worry about it.  99% of the time.  There are still a few instances where caching makes sense, but caching doesn't need to involve session state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the application recycles, the windows process the site is running in `w3wp.exe` ends and a new one is created.  It's also possible a site has multiple worker processes for one application pool. In that case they all end and 1 spins up, and new worker processes will be created as they are needed.

When this happens, anything the website code was storing in memory is lost.  This includes In Process Session information.

However .Net Session State can work in two modes, in process, or database. You can run the aspnet_regsql tool to create a database in sql server for storing session information. Then you can change the web.config to have session run in the database. You can use the same session apis, they work the same in both modes. But putting it in database mode causes it to persist everything to the database instead of in process memory. Then when AppPool recycles, you lose nothing.

RegSql Doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229862(v=vs.100).aspx

A well designed ASP.Net Site (be it MVC, Web Forms, WebApi(1/2)) etc. should be designed to be able to fully recover from any recycles. A site recycle should not break your web site.

Comment: Also worth noting, that an app shouldn't need to store much in session, really nothing.  I've built hundreds of apps without ever using session.  I use cookies but the only time I do that is if I need data in the JS layer to persist accross page loads for maintaining UI State, like remembering what tab you were on, etc.  This also takes into consideration claims authentication which can contain info you need for state as part of the authentication layer (user id, user name, roles, etc) and that persists to a claim cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Recycling the Application Pool will blow away your AppDomain and everything in it, including all static values.

This is why it loses session state in the first place.

You probably want a database.

Comment: For example I had a singleton user defined collection. It would also be vanished and blow up? This User defined collection will contain deserialize able string to objects. 
I want to keep that des-serializable string. So, this singleton collection will also vanishes?

Comment: The singleton will be re-initialized in the new app domain - all in memory state within the app domain is lost when the application pool recycles.

Answer (score 1):

SLaks pretty much answered your question. Here is the solution -

In ASP.Net MVC, we do not use Session State like Web Form.

However, you can still use Session State, but you want to use external Session State provider instead of default [InProc mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) - values and variables are stored in memory on the local Web server.

You have few options -

- StateServer
- [SQLServer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604)
- [Custom mode using Redis Cache like Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/).