# .Net IIS Application Pool Capacity

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7.5

Recently my productions sites got down for some reason, I recycled the app pool and everything seems working.

I have questions here,

Does app pool has a Capacity or limit on hosting applications ?
What does recycling a app pool does?
As I shared above what might be the cause for applications was not working and started working after pool recycling ?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: It is a concept more than 15 years old, so why cannot you Google? https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/10307/understanding-application-pool-recycling-and-how-to-fine-tune-for-use-with-outsys/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when application pool re-cycles in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994243/what-happens-when-application-pool-re-cycles-in-asp-net-mvc)