# How to integrate TPL Dataflow in ASP NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, tpl-dataflow

Hello have looked with intense interest lately to `TPL Dataflow`  and i want to integrate it in my `ASP .NET Core` application.
I want to use it as a pipeline where multiple methods from different parts of application can post data to this DataFlow chain.
What i do not know is where do you store your link of blocks  in case you want them to be called from multiple places?

**Producer**

```
public class Producer
{
    private BufferBlock<int> startBlock{get;}
    private ActionBlock<int> ioBlock{get;}
    private IOService service;

    private void InitializeChain()
    {
       this.startBlock=new BufferBlock<int>();
       var transformLink=new TransformBlock<int,string>([something]);
       // some chain of blocks here 
       this.ioBlock=new ActionBlock<int>(async(x)=>await this.service.WriteAsync(x));
       this.startBlock.LinkTo([someBlock]).LinkTo([someOtherBlock])......LinkTo(ioBlock);
    }
    public async Task AddAsync(int data)
    {
        this.BufferBlock.Post(data);
    }
    public Producer(IOService service)
    {
        this.service=service;
        this.InitializeChain();
    }
}
```

**API Producers**
I am envisioning this `Producer` getting called from multiple parts of my application , well use `Controller`-s for brevity:

```
public class C1:Controller
{
    private Producer producer;
    [HttpPost]
    [Route([someroute])
    public async Task SomeRoute(int data)
    {
        await  this.producer.AddAsync(data);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route([someotherroute])
    public async Task SomeOtherRoute(int data)
    {
        await  this.producer.AddAsync(data);
    }
    public C1(Producer producer)
    {
      this.producer=producer;
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
           services.AddSingleton<Producer>();
  }
```

This can be extended to a multiple `Controller` scenario or deeper in the hierarchy.

Now my question would be:
How should the `Producer` that keeps the `Dataflow` chain be injected ? Should it be transient ? Should the `Blocks` be instantiated on every call ?

I do not know if this design is ok.I know TPL Dataflow is threadsafe , but can  it be used this way?

**P.S** I basically do not know in what form to keep my `Dataflow` pipeline and its lifetime , if i want it to be available per the entire scope of my `ASP NET Core` application.
I want to fetch data from multiple endpoints (directly or deeper in the call hierarchy) , batch them ,transform them , and control the way they are in the end written to an external source (`async` operation).
Does this play nice with the already existing `ThreadPool` of `ASP NET Core` ?

**P.S 2**: This question also haunts me for an `Rx` equivalent.

Comment: Is this pipeline intended to be created on each web request, or is it intended to be application-wise, and persist in memory for the whole lifetime of the application? In the second case I suggest to take a look at this: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). TL;DR your pipeline could be recycled along with the application frequently and non-deterministically.

Comment: I think it fits the second scenario since i want this pipeline created once , and then be used from everywhere in my application.I need some place where all my data comes in (across my application) gets transformed , aggregated and then written to somewhere else in batches (maybe).Also what do you mean by recycled ? If i use a singleton object , won't it persist for all app lifetime ?

Comment: AFAIK the singleton object will not survive an `AppDomain` unload/reload in ASP.NET, or the recycling of a w3wp.exe process. I don't know if the ASP.NET Core has any differences. Here are some links that may be helpful: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994243/what-happens-when-application-pool-re-cycles-in-asp-net-mvc), [2](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/02/Use-IIS-Application-Initialization-for-keeping-ASPNET-Apps-alive), [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/).

Comment: Well isn't this true for any operation that you are doing in a `ASP NET Core` application then ? And now thinking about it , doesn't that mean  the `Dataflow` `Mesh` gets reinstantiated after it ceases to exist ? What problems could there appear ?

Comment: It depends on the kind of work that is done by the pipeline. If for example it's producing some unimportant statistics, then I guess that losing some data every now and then will not be a huge deal.

Comment: The thing is that at the end of the (light weight) pipeline i am writing the data in batches to some medium (`Redis`) .I wanted a way to not block the method of the web request( the method not the thread ! )

Comment: Won't be a problem if occasionally the data fail to persist in the underlying storage medium? Is the client able to confirm later that the data were actually persisted, and if not to try sending them again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend not directly linking your controllers to your background processor. For reliability reasons, there should be a persistent queue in between them. This can be an Azure Queue, Amazon Simple Queue, or even something old school like MSMQ or a database.

Your processor can be independent (Azure Function, Amazon Lambda, or old school like Win32 service), or it can be part of your web app (ASP.NET Core hosted service).

Your controller writes to the persistent queue and then returns. Your processor then reads messages from the queue and processes them. Your processor is what would use TPL Dataflow or Rx - whichever is more natural.

Comment: I do have a persistent queue : Redis.I  am referring strictly to the producer side now.I see the processor as a singleton service whose sole purpose is to publish messages to  a `Redis` channel.In its belly i would either use TPL Dataflow or  push messages to a ConcurrentQueue working in tandem with a loop that would fetch from said queue and publish to Redis.I do not want to block the caller's executing method by `await`-ing the Redis write.Do you think this layer on the producer's side is unnecessary ? The consumer would be a hosted service like you mentioned.

Comment: By returning before the data is persisted, you'd be losing all the benefits of a persistent queue. I strongly recommend not returning early and writing directly to Redis.

Comment: It's this part that is raising flags: `I do not want to block the caller's executing method by await-ing the Redis write.` - the controller *has* to await until the work is persisted; that's the whole point of a persistent queue. If the controller returns and leaves the persisting to some other code, then you lose the benefit of the persistent queue.

Comment: I guess i just wanted to avoid the saying `altering a system by the mere observance of it`.